# 3D Touch: registerForPreviewing in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, 3dtouch

Here the scenario is, UICollectionView is in UITableViewCell and UITableView is on UIViewController, now I have to use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`if 3D Touch is not available I need to register it in UICollectionView Cell, `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is working perfectly, but I'm not able to register `registerForPreviewing` in the cell for 3D Touch. What is the way to register this in `cell`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3D Touch can register only on `UIViewController` or `instance of UIViewController class`

Now, you have to register your tableView with 3D Touch. The only problem is getting selected UICollectionViewCell which is in UITableViewCell.

You can get that in `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate` delegate methods

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

    //Get indexPath for selected tableViewCell using location
    guard let tableViewIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else {
        return nil
    }

    //Get selected tableViewCell
    //NestedCell is UITableViewCell
    guard let tableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: tableViewIndexPath) as? NestedCell else {
        return nil
    }

    //CollectionView which is in every tableViewCell
    let collectionView = tableViewCell.collectionView

    //Get the location of collectionView
    let collectionViewLocation = tableView.convert(location, to: collectionView)

    //Get indexPath of selected collectionViewCell
    guard let collectionViewIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: collectionViewLocation) else {
        return nil
    }

    //Finally, you get selected collectionViewCell
    guard let collectionViewCell = tableViewCell.collectionView.cellForItem(at: collectionViewIndexPath) else {
        return nil
    }

    let preview = PreviewVC()
    preview.view.backgroundColor = collectionViewCell.backgroundColor
    preview.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 600)

    //Modify CGRect/frame for selected collectionview cell
    var sourceRect = collectionViewCell.frame
    sourceRect.origin.x = sourceRect.origin.x - collectionView.contentOffset.x

    let y = tableViewCell.frame.origin.y + collectionViewCell.frame.origin.y
    sourceRect.origin.y = y
    previewingContext.sourceRect = sourceRect
    return preview

}
```

output:

[image]