# 3D touch not available for the device swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit

I want to add a feature to my app that requires 3D touch, but it says forceTouchCapability is not available.
I tried it on three virtual devices (iPhone 14 - iPhone 14 Pro - iPhone 11) and it is same for all the devices and all are up to date.
This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
    }
    
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        switch traitCollection.forceTouchCapability {
        case .available:
            print("Available")
        case .unavailable:
            print("Unavailable")
        case .unknown:
            print("Unknown")
        @unknown default:
            print("dd")
        }
    }
}
```

I have also downloaded many projects from github, using the feature of 3D touch.
They also show the same error as my project.
What is wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3D Touch was removed in the iPhone 11 series and none of the newer iPhones have it, so what you are seeing is correct - you are testing `forceTouchCapability` on devices which don't support Force Touch.

If you want to see which iPhone models support 3D Touch, see [Adjust how iPhone responds to your touch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph77bcdd132/17.0/ios/17.0), scroll to the **Adjust settings for touch-and-hold gestures** section, then select `iPhone with 3D Touch`. As you can see, out of the iPhone supporting iOS 17, only iPhone XS and XS Max support 3D Touch.

Also see [this](https://9to5mac.com/2021/12/29/comment-3d-touch-was-one-of-the-best-technologies-apple-ever-created-and-i-still-miss-it/) article explaining that 3D Touch is unavailable in iPhones introduced after 2018.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So, how can I do the same described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781903/3d-touch-registerforpreviewing-in-uicollectionviewcell

Comment: @DevHome98 I'd recommend using a long press gesture. 3D Touch is not available.

Comment: @DevHome98 if you check the docs for the [registerForPreviewing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621463-registerforpreviewing) method which the linked question uses, you can clearly see that it has been deprecated since iOS 13. You need to use [UIContextMenuInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction) instead as the deprecation notes state.